# TraceSource messages not being logged to the trx file when unit tests are run by vstest.console.exe

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, tracesource

I have a unit tests dll that is run using [vstest.console.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx). Inside the unit tests I log some debugging information using a [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx). When I run the unit tests in Visual Studio, I can see the logs in the output windows, but when I run it by vstest.console.exe with /Logger:trx option, the output logs are not there.

I tried to replace the TraceSource with the static [Trace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) and this actually worked and the logs show in trx file. Any Idea why the logs from the TraceSource do not show as opposed to showing when using Trace ?

My usage of the TraceSource is as follows:

```
TraceSource traceSource = new TraceSource("TraceSourceTraceLogger");
traceSource.Listeners.Clear();
traceSource.Listeners.Add(new DefaultTraceListener());
traceSource.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
var sourceSwitch = new SourceSwitch("TraceSourceTraceLoggerSwitch") { Level = SourceLevels.All };
traceSource.Switch = sourceSwitch;
traceSource.TraceInformation("This is a debug message");
```

And the App.config has:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out that the TraceSource I was using was a static instance inside a static class.

A static TraceSource in a non-static class works though.